# My script open all "Read More" Boxes but should only be 1

Tags: html, css, box

I used the code from this site(https://html-online.com/articles/simple-popup-box/) to create some read more buttons in my website. But they are linked together so when they press 1 they all open. Is there a quick tweak I can apply without having to copy the script and the whole CSS 10x and then rename it?

Comment: The article you posted is about opening popups not read more. Even if you had the exact same thing, you should still post your own code here. That link may not exist 5 years from now but the question will.

Answer (score 0):

The probem is JS, which says (I'll simplify class names):

```
$(".button1").click(function()
       $('.class1').show();
```

this way it will show **all** the elements with the `class1` class. If you want to open only one, you need to give it an id, and have a button for each, **or, even better** do this:

```
docuemnt.getElementByID("asd").addEventListener("click", function(){
    //do the showing
})
```

or, if it isn't working:

```
let a = document.querySelectorAll(".class1");
a.addEventListener("click", function(){
  //do the showing
})
```